# Overriding bootstrap 4 with CDN link and SCSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

All of the answers I've seen on here with respect to overriding Bootstrap (v4) with SCSS assume Bootstrap (or Bootstrap's CSS file?) is downloaded to a site directory.

I'm importing bootstrap via the CDN link into my layout.html page and have links to all other CSS files after it. The one linked to SCSS is listed dead last. I'd link to override Bootstrap with SCSS this way.

As a quick example, I couldn't change the font used as the title for every page. The section in `layout.html` is like so:

```
 <head>
    <!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Fontawesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=IM+Fell+English+SC" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Additional CSS use of static dir structure require w/ jinja-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/styles.css') }}">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container siteTitle h-100">
        <div class="row h-100 mx-auto">
            <div class="col-md-12" >
                <h1 id="siteName">Foo</h1>
                <h3 id="siteSubTitle">Bar</h3>
                <h6 id="siteTagLine">Baz</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- end header container -->
</body>
```

And the SCSS looks like this at the moment:

```
$siteFont: 'IM Fell English SC', serif;


#siteName, #siteSubTitle, #siteTagLine {
    $font-family-serif: $siteFont !default;
}
```

Other variations (e.g., ditching the `$siteFont` variable and placing the font name directly in the CSS rule) have been tried. How do I pull this off?

Comment: The fact that Bootstrap is coming from a CDN won't affect how your CSS overrides work. Are you sure you're using the proper selector? What are you overriding with the variable `$font-family-serif`?

Comment: Oh - if you're trying to override variables from Bootstrap's pre-compiled SCSS, you won't be able to do that. You'll need to override Boostrap's flat compiled CSS by directly targeting elements and properties you want to change - not variables.

Comment: @JonUleis Bootstrap chose a default font for those headlines. I wanted to sub in a  Google font. I read somewhere on here that  $font-family-serif: was the variable I needed to target. Should I skip SCSS and just write CSS. Bootstrap isn't immutable.

Comment: Those variables (anything starting with a `$`) only exist in Bootstrap's SCSS. You're linking to their compiled CSS, so you'll have to target the actual CSS properties (`font-family`, etc) rather than Sass variables.

Comment: @JonUleis  And that was the distinction I was missing!

Answer (score 8):

So the short answer to this is - you can't.

That is, you can't change any SASS variables and still use Bootstrap from the CDN. This is because that version of Bootstrap has already been compiled, so the variables (such as $font-family-base or $enable-responsive-font-sizes) have already been substituted in.

As in the discussion above, if you want to change any SASS variables, you need to compile your own version of Bootstrap.

For simple changes this does of course feel like overkill. So it's not wrong to continue using the CDN version and just override things at the CSS level instead. For more extensive changes, SASS is of course the way to go.