# Override and set Bootstrap gutter width whilst using CDN

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, grid, gutter

Been using Bootstrap 4 via NPM and importing it into my main SASS file. Before the import, I declare:
`$grid-gutter-width: 26px !default;`

and then import the bootstrap package.

Recently I've been toying with using the bootstrap CDN, and removing the import from my SASS file, but what I am struggling with is setting and overriding the grid gutter width as before. The CDN is referenced  just before the closing `</body>` tag, and then in my app.scss, I still declare the grid gutter as above, but the gutter still comes through as 30px (15px each side of the column).

So what am I doing wrong, or is it a case that this cannot be done if using the CDN?

Answer (score 0):

When you use SASS and set Bootstrap variables this creates a customized version of the bootstrap.css when you compile.
The CDN is already precompiled into CSS with all the default variable values.
In order to achieve the same results when using the CDN you have to override all the individual style declarations derived from those values.

See also:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57702046/6127393